# Display countries, states and cities in different components using routing in angular

Tags: angular

I have a json of countries with state and city. I want to display first country list on country component and state list on state component then city on city component with routing.

Please help me how to display data on parent to child (multilevel) in angular 6/7.

JSON Data -

```
{
"country": [{
    "id": 1,
    "countryName": "India",
    "state": [{
        "id": 11,
        "stateName": "Andhra Pradesh",
        "city": [
            "Anantapur",
            "Chittoor",
            "East Godavari",
            "Guntur",
            "Krishna",
            "Kurnool",
            "Nellore",
            "Prakasam",
            "Srikakulam",
            "Visakhapatnam",
            "Vizianagaram",
            "West Godavari",
            "YSR Kadapa"
        ]
    }]
}]
```

}

Country Component - 
Here showing country lists, after clicking on list show its particular state afterwards cities.

```
<ul>
   <li *ngFor="let x of country">{{x.countryName}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: what did you try so far? you can create a stackblitz and add a link to your question.

Answer (score 1):

TLDR; What you are looking for is nearly the basic [angular tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5).

Entry point is your `country.component.ts` and fetching the data just ones and not on each component. So you should provide a service `DataService`. There you should push your json-data. All your json-entries got ids, so i would just give the `id` in the route.

```
<ul>
   <li *ngFor="let country of countries" [routerLink]="['states',country.id]">{{country.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

After this your `states.component.ts` should look like the same, but instead of countries and states you doing states and cities.

```
<ul>
   <li *ngFor="let state of states" [routerLink]="['cities',state.id]">{{state.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

Inside the `states.component` you construct the service and search for the right object in your country array to the get the state you need.

```
export class StateComponent implements OnInit {

    country : any; //again or model Country
    id: number;
    private sub: any;

  constructor(
    private route : ActivatedRoute,
    private dataService : DataService,
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
       this.id = +params['id']; // (+) converts string 'id' to a number
    });

      this.dataService._data
      .subscribe(
        next => {
          this.country = _data.find(id); //search logic here inside array countries for your country with id, use the normal js find
        },
        () => {
          console.log('Error');
        },
        () => {
          console.log('Complete');
        }
      );
  }
  }
```

The path in your routing-module should look like this:

```
  {
    path: 'states/:id',
    component : StatesComponent,
  },
       {
    path: 'cities/:id',
    component : CitiesComponent,
  }
```

You can set all this paths as [children](https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-4-crisis-center-feature). Keywords for you: service with observables.

`DataService` be like:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProjectService {

    private dataSource = new BehaviorSubject(undefined);
    _data = this.dataSource.asObservable();

    constructor(){}

    setDataSource(jsonData : any) {
        this.dataSource.next(jsonData);
    }
}
```